# Android geo fence limit

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing

I am using `geofence` to draw on map.
Below is my code:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> mGeofence = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        for (int j = 0; j < path.getmPolygon().size(); j++) {
            mGeofence.add(path.getmPolygon().get(j));
        }
        if (mGeofence != null && path.getmPolygon().size() >= 3) {
            PolygonOptions polyoptions = new PolygonOptions();
            polyoptions.addAll(mGeofence).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(8f);

            mMap.addPolygon(polyoptions);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Path Invalid Polygon");
        }
```

Google I/O session tells that geofence's limit is 100 session.

So my question is, What do you mean by 100 session ?

```
mMap.addPolygon(polyoptions);
```

Or

```
mGeofence.add(path.getmPolygon().get(j));
```

Comment: Visit This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18920426/3330969)

Comment: @Kedarnath: I have reviewed it, but i have one confusion, which i have shown through my code.Can you please help me in that?

Comment: Ok Dhrupal, I think 100 means by this `mGeofence.add(path.getmPolygon().get(j));` , Also you can run a for loop for 100 on each statement one by one and check your self. I am not sure as I havent done work on this.

Comment: @Kedarnath : Thnx. But what will heppan if i put more than 100 geofence in a map. Will it not drawn or drawn but not actually there.

Comment: Good Morning, I guess it should draw, As I told you, I haventt tried this out, So I can not give you 100% accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Polyline`s to the map has nothing to do with Geofencing. The limitation is imposed on the [geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).