# Adding more than 100 geofences in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence

As per docs it is not possible to add more than 100 geofences per device in android.

I want to know, Is it possible to add more geofences if I have removed the previous ones.

Lets say in my app

- Initially I have added 100 geofences.
- Then removed them all.
- Then added another one.

Now, the last one(after remove all added fences) will be added or not? If not, that means a device can only register 100 geofences in its lifetime. Right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Android limit is 100 geofences per app per device**. So in your case, the last geofence added in third step will be added. Just take into account that adding and removing geofencing are async operations so ensure the removal has actually finished.

You may also go **beyond 100 geofences limit** using approach described in 
[Adding more than 100 geofences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670504/android-need-to-add-more-than-100-geofences/29703326#29703326)

Finally, I work at [MOCA](https://mocaplatform.com), location-based engagement platform and we provide scalable geofencing for iOS & Android available as a SaaS service.