# Geofences - How to track more than 100 locations?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I just wonder if this post [Adding more than 100 geofences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670504/android-need-to-add-more-than-100-geofences) is still the best practice way to handle more than 100 geofences? (Sadly cant comment on it yet, hence the new post)

Its from 2015, so I wonder if there is another way currently?

I am getting my locations (about 170) from Firestore and would like to compare the 100 closest.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. At least the principle behind. You can use location  to find the 100 nearest fences.

Still, two situations might arise, where the approach fails:

- the 100 nearest fences are not covering enough space, i.e. when you have one fence per room in a high building, you have hundreds of fences roughly in the same place
- finding the 100 nearest fences is prohibitively slow, I.e. when you take all building polygons from OSM.

In those cases, you need to develop a hybrid approach by, for example, using r trees and/or aggregate fences until both problems are solved.

Hope this helps...